# ¿Cómo hago que me aparezca diferente título en cada System.out.println?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Mi problema es que en mi clase métodos tengo un public void arreglo, y ahí quiero que cuando lo corra el programa, me de el titulo "primer mes" y poner un numero, luego me aparezca "segundo mes" y poner otro numero, y así consecutivamente hasta llegar al 12, ya que son 12 meses, pero cuando lo corro me aparece todos lo títulos juntos, y no puedo poner mi numero en cada titulo, solo puedo poner los números, pero sin sus títulos correspondientes, si alguien podría ayudarme porfa!!!!!!

MAIN.JAVA

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Metodos cosecha= new Metodos();
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        int op = 0,z,x;

        do {
            System.out.println("MENU");
            System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________");
            System.out.println("1. Cereales Cosechados ");
            System.out.println("2. Imprimir arreglo de Cereales Cosechados ");
            System.out.println("3. Promedio anual  de las Toneladas Cosechadas");
            System.out.println("4. ¿Cuantos meses tuvieron una inferior al promedioa anual ?");
            System.out.println("5. Arreglo 2");
            System.out.println("6. Imprimir arreglo 2");
            System.out.println("7. Calcular Primo");
            System.out.println("8. Suma Primos");
            System.out.println("9. Menor al Promedio");
            System.out.println("10. Salir del Programa");
            System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________");
            System.out.println("Elija una opcion:");
            op=read.nextInt();
            switch (op) {

                case 1:

                    z=12;
                    cosecha.arreglo(z);
                    break;

                case 2:

                    cosecha.imprimir(cosecha.arreg);
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 3:

                    System.out.println("" + cosecha.promedio(cosecha.arreg));
                    break;

                case 4:

                    cosecha.mayor(cosecha.arreg);
                    break;

                case 5:

                    System.out.println("Escribe el tamaño de arreglo para ingesar los numeros ");
                    x = read.nextInt();
                    cosecha.arrrN(x);
                    break;

                case 6:

                    cosecha.nuemro(cosecha.arregloN);
                    System.out.println();
                    break;

                case 7:

                    System.out.println(""+cosecha.CulcalNPrimo(cosecha.arregloN));
                    break;

                case 8:

                    System.out.println("Resultado\t"+cosecha.SumaPrimo(cosecha.arregloN));break;

                case 9:

                    cosecha.menor(cosecha.arreg);
                    break;
            }
        } while (op != 10);
    }
}
```

METODOS.JAVA

```
package com.company;
import org.omg.CORBA.PUBLIC_MEMBER;

import  java.util.Scanner;
public class Metodos {
    Scanner read= new Scanner(System.in);
    int []arreg;

    public void arreglo (int z){

        arreg=new int [z];
        for(int i=0;i<z;i++) {
            System.out.println("Primer Mes");
            System.out.println("Segundo Mes");
            System.out.println("Tercer Mes");
            System.out.println("Cuarto Mes");
            System.out.println("Quinto Mes");
            System.out.println("Sexto Mes");
            System.out.println("Septimo Mes");
            System.out.println("Octavo Mes");
            System.out.println("Noveno Mes");
            System.out.println("Decimo Mes");
            System.out.println("Decimo Primero Mes");
            System.out.println();
            arreg[i] = read.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public void  imprimir(int[] arreglo){
        for (int i : arreglo)

            System.out.print("\t" + i);


    }
    double b=0;
    public double promedio (int [] arreglo){
        int f=0;
        for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++) {
            f +=arreglo[i];
        }
        b=f/arreglo.length;

        return b;
    }
    public void mayor (int [] arreglo) {
        int x =0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i] > b) {
                x += 1;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(""+x);
    }
    public void menor (int [] arreglo) {
        int x =0;

        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i] < b) {
                x += 1;

            }
        }
        System.out.println(""+x);
    }
    int[] arregloN;
    public void arrrN(int x){
        arregloN=new int [x];
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            System.out.println("cantidad del la cosecha");
            arregloN[i] = read.nextInt();
        }

    }

    public void nuemro (int arreglo[]){
        for (int i : arreglo)
            System.out.print("\t" + i);
        ;

    }
    public int CulcalNPrimo(int arreglo[]){
        int c=0;
        for (int j=0;j<arreglo.length;j++) {
            c = arreglo[j] - 1;
            while ((arreglo[j] % c) != 0) {
                c--;

            }

            if (c == 1) {
                System.out.println("Es primo\t" + arreglo[j]);
            }else{
                System.out.println("No es primo");
            }
        }
        return c;
    }
    public int SumaPrimo(int []arreglo){
        int c=0, e=0;
        for (int j=0;j<arreglo.length;j++) {
            c = arreglo[j] - 1;
            while ((arreglo[j] % c) != 0) {
                c--;

            }

            if (c == 1) {
                e+=arreglo[j];
            }
        }

        return e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu codigo, hace exactamente lo que decis. Estas haciendo 12 prints en cada iteración, porque es lo que escribiste exactamente.

```
for(int i=0;i<z;i++) {
        System.out.println("Primer Mes");
        System.out.println("Segundo Mes");
        System.out.println("Tercer Mes");
        System.out.println("Cuarto Mes");
        System.out.println("Quinto Mes");
        System.out.println("Sexto Mes");
        System.out.println("Septimo Mes");
        System.out.println("Octavo Mes");
        System.out.println("Noveno Mes");
        System.out.println("Decimo Mes");
        System.out.println("Decimo Primero Mes");
        System.out.println();
        arreg[i] = read.nextInt();
    }
```

Ahora, vos queres decirle que imprima un texto, y tome un valor para cada texto impreso.

Entonces, simplifiquemos el problema. Escribamos un solo texto en cada iteracion y tomemos un valor, como por ejemplo de la siguiente forma:

```
for(int i=0;i<z;i++) {
    System.out.println("Mes " + i.toString() + ":");
    System.out.println();
    arreg[i] = read.nextInt();
}
```

Eso va a imprimir, para cada vuelta del for, un texto como "Mes 1:", una linea en blanco, y despues va a pedir un dato.